# Import many nodes to osm file

Tags: import, openstreetmap

I have 500+ places with name, latitude and longitude. Is there any tools for import these nodes to OSM file from command line, or how can i add them to osm? Can I put simple xml tags for these places to the end of osm file?

Comment: Are you talking about a local (your own) OSM file or the main OSM database? For the main OSM database please read the [import guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines) first and contact the import mailing list and local community.

Comment: @scai, I want to add nodes to local osm file

Comment: In that case adding the relevant XML tags should be sufficient.